# image.png problem in Qt design

Tags: qgis, python, qt-designer

I made a python plugin for qgis 3.4 and I built the interface in Qt design.
I have the problem when I insert an image.
I create a Label in qt design and configure the directory on pixmap, on Qt design it is displayed well.
I perform the refresh on qgis but when I open the plugin the image cannot be seen.
Who can help me?